# SQL Admission Count using row_number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

I'm new in SQL Server learner and I'm stuck in simple problem to count the admission using SQL Server in healthcare data set.

Sample table:

```
create table admissions
(
HIC char(1),
DateFrom date,
DateTo date 
);
```

Test data:

```
insert into admissions values('A','2018-01-19','2018-01-19');
insert into admissions values('A','2018-01-19','2018-01-19');
insert into admissions values('A','2018-07-13','2018-07-13');
insert into admissions values('A','2018-05-09','2018-05-09');
insert into admissions values('A','2018-09-25','2018-09-25');
insert into admissions values('A','2018-10-05','2018-10-05');
insert into admissions values('A','2018-10-28','2018-10-28');
insert into admissions values('B','2018-10-05','2018-10-05');
insert into admissions values('B','2018-10-05','2018-10-05');
insert into admissions values('C','2018-01-19','2018-01-19');
insert into admissions values('D','2018-01-19','2018-01-19');
```

[image]

So for Patient A, admitted twice in on same day, so we will count 1 admissions on 1/19/2019 and rest other will be calculated as unique count.

Comment: Is column E supposed to be the number of admissions so far in that day? So 1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1? Or something else? You're not clear

Comment: Yes, I need to calculate the Admission count for millions of record

Comment: Oh, sorry, I understand now

Comment: Admission count per patient, per day, or total?  Please provide sample output.

Comment: Admission count per patient per day. So, In the column D, i have manually calculated Admission count. 
For Pt. A, admitted twice on same day (01/19/2019) but i will count 1 and for rest of day i will count as individual count since the date of admission is different from consecutive rows.  

For Pt B, Admitted twice on same day, I will count it as 1 admit and other row will be 0

I hope it clear my objective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the exact output you wanted:

```
with data as ( select HIC, DateFrom, DateTo, 
row_number() over (partition by HIC, DateFrom order by HIC) as AdmissionRunningTotal,
SUM(1) over (partition by HIC, DateFrom order by HIC) as AdmissionSum
from admissions
)
select HIC, DateFrom, case when AdmissionSum = AdmissionRunningTotal 
                           then 1 else 0 
                      end as AdmissionCount  
from data 
order by HIC, DateFrom, 3 desc;
```

There are other ways of doing this, this was just easiest for me.

Obviously a real application would want to check overlapping data ranges etc.

[DB Fiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1b691cc911b4b27d89318e9e301f3078)